# Iterator for only one row of a vector of a vector

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

Let's say I have a 2D array:

```
vector<vector<int8_t>> table =
{
    {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
    {22, 46, 12, 2, 35, 4 },
    {4, 5, 6, 22, 11, 8 },

};
```

How can I search only one row for a specific element.  I tried to use iterators, but how to tell them to start at the beginning of a row?

So, always I know which row to search, so that not need be taken into the loop.

e.g search row 1 for element 12.

Comment: `it->begin()` and `it->end()` maybe?

Comment: That will search the whole array.

Comment: No it won't. Since `it` points at a vector of the outer vector.

Comment: Vectors don't know anything about multiple dimensions. You don't have a two dimensional vector, you have a vector of vectors. Iterating the outer vector will only return the inner vectors, it won't **search** them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a general function. For example

```
size_t find_element( const std::vector<std::vector<int>> &v,
                     std::vector<std::vector<int>>::size_type n,
                     int value )
{
    if ( v.size() <= n ) return -1;

    auto it = std::find( v[n].begin(), v[n].end(), value );

    return it == v[n].end() ? -1 : std::distance( v[n].begin(), it );
}
```

Or you could make it a template function

```
template <class T>

size_t find_element( const std::vector<std::vector<T>> &v,
                     typename std::vector<std::vector<T>>::size_type n,
                     const T &value )
{
    if ( v.size() <= n ) return -1;

    auto it = std::find( v[n].begin(), v[n].end(), value );

    return it == v[n].end() ? -1 : std::distance( v[n].begin(), it );
}
```

Instead of `typename std::vector<std::vector<T>>::size_type n` you may use simply `size_t n`

Comment: Is there anyway to get a more general function, so for int8_t, int16_t etc..  Anyhow this looks like a very good solution.  Thanks.

Comment: @user1876942 You simply can make the function I showed templated. See my updated post.

Answer (score 2):

```
auto it = std::search(table[row_index].begin(),table[row_index].end(),value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Treat each row like any other vector.

```
auto row_beg = table[1].begin();
auto row_end = table[1].end();
auto find_it = std::find(row_beg, row_end, 12);
if (find_it != row_end)
    std::cout << "Found.\n";
```

Comment: Thanks, is there anyway to know when the item is found, fort example 12 found at element 3 and then break?

Comment: @user1876942 You mean get the index? You can try something like `find_it - row_beg` or `std::distance(row_beg, find_it)`.